# Variable in Replace SQl

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, replace

i'm beginner in php sql ... 
so i need your help . 
I'm trying to create a modification system for the database using php CRUD and i want to add a replace function to change in example in the entire table just from tipping it in the form , so every time it gonna be a new word .
my question is how to do this ? how to use variable to replace something in the database using form ? 
Thanks .

Comment: There are plenty of examples of how to build a CRUD system, do some research and if you have a specific coding problem, then please ask for help then.

Comment: Hi Khalil. You need to show some work/effort. No one on SO will write code for you. The purpose of SO is to help someone through a bug or an issue mostly. So you need to find tutorials elsewhere and try building a system. Then when you get stuck, search SO to see if anyone else had a similar issue and which response helped him. If you can't find an answer in an already answered question only then post a question and someone from the community will help you resolve the issue.